# Ubuntu 18.04 Black Screen after Blanking Screen

Tags: graphics, 18.04

When my computer blanks the screen after the timeout (10 minutes) or after I turn off the monitors and turn them back on some time later, I only see a black screen with the mouse pointer. I can move the mouse pointer, but nothing else happens.

I am able to switch to the console with Ctrl + Alt + F3 and then switching back to the display with Ctrl + Alt + F1 gives me the login screen. But after logging in, I get the same problem.

Restarting gdm3 from the console does not seem to help. It gets stuck initializing and then I have to hard shutdown. The only thing that works is to restart the machine from the console, but that is annoying.

Has anyone else experienced this problem or have any ideas on how to fix this?

My machine is Ubuntu 18.04 with the 4.15.0-32-generic kernel.

Comment: try `ctrl+d` or `alt+tab`, to get desktop or your previous app.

Answer (score 1):

Andrew. I experienced something similar to what you're getting. I have 18.04 with  Linux 4.15.0-29-generic. This started to happen to me after I did install Nvidia Proprietary Drivers. If you updated from 16.04 where you were using proprietary drivers it can be the problem.

I would suggest to remove all the "Nvidia" drivers.

```
sudo apt-get --purge remove nvidia*
```

And maybe reconfigure X server.

```
sudo service gdm3 stop
sudo dpkg-reconfigure xserver-xorg
```

Helped me. Had it working with Nouveau.