# When idle screen blanked with mouse pointer but not turned off

Tags: drivers, nvidia, 18.04, suspend, display

I'm using Ubuntu 18.04.

When computer inactive or lock it manually screen becomes black with mouse pointer on it. Actually it looks like is still turned on.

I would like to get it turned off for energy saving.

I have installed:

```
NVIDIA X Server
NVIDIA Driver Version: 390.77
Monitor Dell P2717H
Video Card: GeForce GTX 1050 Ti
```

Answer (score 0):

I've uninstalled NVidia X Server as described in [Ubuntu 18.04 Black Screen after Blanking Screen question answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1067714/879850) and that helped